# when i try to download anything from terminal i have this

Tags: 13.10

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: 13.10 is end of life so support from AskUbuntu ended. Please upgrade to 14.04.

Comment: @Rinzwind Hi:) how do you know this is for 13.10 ? is that error appear only on 13.10 ?

Comment: @lion That is the fun part about tags :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm  oh yes :D

Answer (score 1):

You can get this if you have some kind of package manager running at the same time. Only one process can access package management at a time. Has hit me a couple times when I forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete lock file with command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Comment: That seems like it could be dangerous: lock files exist for a reason.